# Backbone: reload collection or fetch on page load

Tags: json, backbone.js, reload, fetch

Which way is better: render page with json data to init collection (`reload()`) on load page or load page and then run `fetch()` to build collection.

For heavy list of items.

Comment: if i were you i'd use `fetch()` because of few reasons: 1) - you can easely refetch you collection with no deps of html. 2) - you have no need to do any staff on server side to build well-formated json 3) - you will keep collection logic incapsulated, and avoid outer deps.